# Traduction de "a practitioner"

Tags: vocabulaire, sport

Je traduis actuellement un texte anglais en français, qui parle d'un art martial russe, le Systema. Il n'y a pas d'adjectif pour ce sport, comme *boxeur* ou *catcheur*, et je rencontre des difficultés lorsqu'il faut traduire le mot *practitioner*.

En français, le mot *pratiquant* est employé dans un contexte religieux, et celui de *praticien* concerne la médecine. Quel mot français pourrais-je utiliser pour « celui/celle qui pratique » ?

Comment: Dans ce contexte, "athlète" pourrait convenir, même si cela ne répond pas exactement à la question.

Comment: If the martial arts are truly arts, wouldn’t one who practices them be an “artist,” or at least a “martial artist”=”artiste martial”/"artiste en art martial russe"/"artiste en Systema"?

Comment: @PapaPoule for known martial arts, it sounds very weird, except if you are watching a show

Answer (score 4):

> Je **pratique** un art martial.
>   Je suis une personne **pratiquant** un art martial.

Comme vous le soulignez "*pratiquant*" est généralement utilisé dans un sens religieux quand il est utilisé comme un nom commun. Par exemple : «Je suis pratiquant». Sans contexte, cette phrase signifie que je suis plus ou moins fortement impliqué dans une religion.
Dans votre cas, il n'y a aucune ambiguïté si le contexte est présent, que ce soit dans la phrase elle même, ou dans la phrase précédente. Le tout est d'être certain qu'on ne puisse pas confondre avec un pratiquant religieux.

Aussi, la réponse de [lkl](https://french.stackexchange.com/users/7684/lkl) me fait penser que pour le judo, on ne dit pas "judistes", mais "judoka", car c'est le terme japonais (créateur du sport). Peut-être devriez vous utiliser le terme russe définissant quelqu'un qui pratique le Systema ?

[Papa Poule](https://french.stackexchange.com/users/6011/papa-poule) fait remarquer aussi que l'on est certainement distrait par le mot "Systema" quin 'est pas naturel pour nous, et qui peut induire notre oreille en erreur sur la phrase complète. Ainsi, en transposant avec le Judo, la phrase «Un pratiquant de Judo» semble tout à fait naturelle, on peut alors dire :

> Un pratiquant de Systema

Comment: Merci pour vos suggestions, même si je ne suis pas pleinement satisfaite par ces deux mots... adepte sonne un peu amateur, et pratiquant un peu trop spirituel, même hors contexte religieux... Mais enfin, je vais devoir m'en contenter j'imagine ! Le côté pragmatique de la langue anglaise est décidément toujours difficile à transposer en français...

Comment: +1 I know very little about martial arts, but I’ve always been led to believe that there is an important spiritual side to them & to their practice. If this be the case (& if, as the OP says, “pratiquant” has spiritual connotations), then I think your answers would be perfect for describing someone who practiced such spiritual arts/sports.  One question, though: I notice that you didn’t propose “Je suis un/e pratiquant/e d’un art martial.” (which I think would also be a nice way to capture both sides of such arts/sports) Was there any reason for proposing it as a participle but not as a noun?

Comment: @PapaPoule You're right, the spiritual part is very important in martial arts / combat sports. The reason I didn't propose "Je suis un pratiquant de Systema" is because the noun sounds weird imo... I can't see a sentence where it would fit... do you ?

Comment: No, not directly with/next to "[de/du] Systema," but maybe constructing it like you did to buffer & define it a bit: "pratiquant (the participle) [d'] un art martial [russe qui s'appelle Systema]" instead of jumping right to "pratiquant (the participle) le Systema" would not sound as weird. Regardless, maybe it's just because 'le Systema' is not as well known as 'le Judo,' for example (or maybe it's just me), but I find that "pratiquant (the participle) [le] Judo" and even as a noun ("un pratiquant de/du Judo") sound less weird (or at least more familiar) than when used with "Systema."

Comment: @PapaPoule The most natural way with Judo is "un pratiquant de judo" ("du" sounds weird), I'll add it to the answer. On the other hand, "un pratiquant d'un art martial" sounds odd for me, I think because of the double "un"... But that's a very good point to try to make a sentence with "Judo" instead of "Systema" to find the right one to use !

Answer (score 3):

Nécessité est mère d'invention : *systémiste*

- *un systémiste*
- *les systémistes*
- *l'entraînement systémiste*

Answer (score 2):

> Je suis un **adepte** du Systema

Comme l'indique cette [definition](http://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/adepte/1057)

Answer (score 2):

L'[article](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Systema) *Wikipédia* emploie deux fois le mot « *combattant* » (sans doute originalement le [contexte](http://www.btb.termiumplus.gc.ca/tpv2alpha/alpha-fra.html?lang=fra&srchtxt=combattant&i=1&index=frt) la personne qui participe à la *compétition*; ou en contexte *militaire*, mais aussi [généralement](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/combattant), et qui en vient [*aux mains*](http://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/combattant/17374?q=combattant#17242) avec quelqu'un); tout à fait adéquat (*le combattant en/au Systema*).

Autrement souvent le mot anglais « [*practitionner*](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/practitioner?s=t) »<sup>1</sup> non pas dans le sens de celui qui pratique (sinon professionnellement), mais dans le sens du [*spécialiste*](http://www.btb.termiumplus.gc.ca/tpv2alpha/alpha-fra.html?lang=fra&i=1&index=alt&__index=alt&codom2nd=&srchtxt=praticien&comencsrch.x=0&comencsrch.y=0) ou de l'*expert* dans un domaine, d'où l'intérêt d'un [commentaire](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/16205/traduction-de-practitioner#comment30245_16205) sur le mot *athlète*, qui sans convenir y réfère. Aussi intéressant (*le spécialiste au/du Systema*).

---

<sub><sup>1</sup> Le sens religieux est évincé par le contexte, comme d'autres [ont dit](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/16206); mais on n'a pas dit quelle audience on visait, et le choix de mots peut varier selon sa nature profane ou par ailleurs constituée de vétérans aguerris aux sports de combat.</sub>

Comment: Je prends pour acquis qu'on a lu les autres réponses. Usuellement l'_adepte_ et celui/celle qui _pratique_, de manière générique. Mais sans présenter un définition du terme anglais, ni du contexte de la phrase ni de l'audience, il est justement difficile de dépasser le générique. Une fois qu'on a quitté le point de vue de l'activité et du loisir, et qu'on décrit la personne en contexte du cadre du combat, c'est là évidemment que le mot combattant prend son sens. Ce n'est pas une question de pragmatisme de la langue, à mon avis. Merci.

Comment: Vu les circonstances, une transposition possible "Je suis *aguerri* au Systema", "Je suis un combattant *aguerri* du Systema".

Answer (score 1):

- formel: je pratique le xxx / je suis pratiquant de xx
- informel: je fais du xxx

NB: attention, adepte a une connotation militante.